# Is it advisable to inherit from std::optional?

Tags: c++

I understand that it the most of the time not good to inherit from STL classes (except for std::exception, etc.) because for example of the lacking virtual destructor and probably other reasons.

However, I have the following code:

```
typedef std::optional<uint64_t> ID;

struct IDS
{
    static ID create();
    static void doSomething(ID id);
    // more static methods
};
```

Inheriting from the optional would allow me to reuse the same name `IDS vs ID` while using it as above (except for removing the static before `doSomething`). Basically it makes using the class easier without loosing the capabilities of optional.

Is this still a bad idea? And if yes, what can go wrong?

Comment: Why do you need a *is a* instead of a *has a*?

Comment: Your current design seems like a poor use of inheritance in general.  Would your inheritance actually satisfy the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)?

Comment: When I see `ID`, I'd expect it to have a value. `std::optional<uint64_t>` could be something like `IDOpt`. That helps you understand why two types are needed - sometimes you're sure you have an ID, sometimes you either do or don't. You shouldn't mix the two, let alone inherit from `std::optional<>` in a struct called `IDS`.

Comment: Because ```ID``` *is an* optional and more practically because I don't want to repeat all the methods of std::optional just to make it a *has a*.  @Eljay

Comment: You could also do a `struct Error1 {}; struct Error2 {}; using MaybeID = variant<uint64_t, Error1, Error2>;`. This way, you can report errors _and_ have the schematics you expect: this is because, you use it like `std::visit([&](const auto& mID) { if constexpr(std::is_same_v<decltype(mID), Error1>) { /* error handler */ } else { /* mID here is uint64_t */ } });`

Comment: If `IDS` is nothing but a bunch of static methods, why is it a struct at all and not a namespace gathering together some free functions?

Comment: I have one static member variable too that I would like to keep private. @NathanPierson

Comment: From the sample code, one would use a `namespace` instead of a derived class. What is the purpose of derivation f all methods are `static`? Repeating all methods would not make much sense either. If you create a class, you generally that class to simplify things. Maybe if you would provide a better example, we might have oher suggestion but as written, there is simply no justification for such abuse.

Comment: It looks like you want to merge ID class and ID-generator class functionalities.Have you considered a Factory class instead?

The main problem with inheritance is once you set this relation it is a part of the interface forever. Any change in the interface leads to changes in the related code, so containment is usually a better option. Free functions give even more flexibility.

Comment: The actual guideline is that it is *strongly* inadvisable to derive from a class/struct with a non-`virtual` destructor. This affects classes in the C++ standard library (including most containers) that don't have virtual destructors. Practically, deriving from such classes is either a code smell or a sign of a design error (often both).   Also: STL is obsolete terminology - you're actually referring to the C++ standard library (although there is a relationship between STL and C++ standard library, they are different things).

Comment: Inheritance to conveniently reuse name is no good justification. As others point out, if all you have is static methods then you're better off with a `namespace` which is about as far from class inheritance as behaviour gets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this still a bad idea? And if yes, what can go wrong?

As you already stated, inheriting from classes without virtual destructor leads to UB when destroyed from base class.

In addition, when inheriting from 3rd party library classes, you also depends of future interface.

You might be in trouble when/if `std::optional` adds functions with same name (especially constructors). Depending of the "conflicts", your code might no longer compile, or worst, select the wrong overload and behave not as you expect.

Note that it is not only member functions, but also apply to free functions and so ADL. So it also applies when removing methods/function/overload (unlikely for `std` though).

Less immediate problematic, even without conflicts, is that interface of your class change with function not necessary matching your expected interface.